# some people abroad cannot access my website

Tags: apache, dns

I get signals that people outside my country (nl) can not access my website. they say they see the Apache placeholder. It is just in some cases.

Is there something wrong with my dns?

```
 m.skiweather.eu149.210.237.45A
 skiweather.eu149.210.237.45A
 mail.skiweather.eu149.210.237.45A
 skiweather.eumail.skiweather.euMX (10)
 smtp.skiweather.eu149.210.237.45A
 pop.skiweather.eu149.210.237.45A
 www.skiweather.eu149.210.237.45A
 skiweather.eudns1.vpshosting.nlNS
 skiweather.eudns2.vpshosting.nlNS
 skiweather.eudns1.vpshosting.nl info@vpshosting.nl 2014081800 14400 3600 604800 3600SOA
 skiweather.eudns3.vpshosting.nlNS
 *.skiweather.eu149.210.237.45A
 gfx.skiweather.eu149.210.237.45A
 cdn.skiweather.eu149.210.237.45A
 skiweather.eugoogle-site-verification=gtRAq2UWkOKRq1ITaaUuUhxqDh077OwH5aadHCX7TbcTXT
 @.skiweather.euv=spf1 a mx ip4:149.210.237.45 include:_spf.google.com ~allSPF
 skiweather.eu2a01:7c8:aabb:5e4:5054:ff:fe74:b8cdAAAA
```

Answer (score 3):

Your DNS seems fine. Checking all your 3 nameservers return the same, correct, IP:

```
dig @dns1.vpshosting.nl skiweather.eu
dig @dns2.vpshosting.nl skiweather.eu
dig @dns3.vpshosting.nl skiweather.eu
```

In addition, https://intodns.com/skiweather.eu doesn't report any problems.

A problem though is that the `https` site (https://skiweather.eu/) returns:

```
Welcome to skiweather.eu
To change this page, upload a new index.html to your private_html folder
```

This is unrelated to DNS and regards configuration on your webserver which seems to be Apache httpd. So you'll have to check the `<VirtualHost>` block for port `:443`. You should make it look like the one for `:80` (but do not remove the certificate related directives).

p.s your SSL certificate is self signed and not good. If you care to have proper https on your site have a look at https://letsencrypt.org/